# How to convert hashcode to index?

Tags: c#, algorithm

To use `GetHashCode()` results as an index, we must convert the `GetHashCode()` to a valid index. Modulus does not work since `GetHashCode()` may be negative. Taking the absolute value then the modulus also doesn't work since `Math.Abs(int.MinValue)` throws an exception.

We use `hashCode & 0x7FFFFFFF` instead before taking the modulus.

I don't understand this transformation. How this is works?

Comment: What is the problem about taking modulus of a negative number?

Comment: since Math.Abs(int.MinValue) throws an exception.

Comment: `Math.Abs(int.MinValue)` does not work because it is 2,147,483,648, which does not fit into `int`. It is the only exceptional case :)

Comment: `0x7FFFFFFF` == `0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111` in binary. So bit-wise AND with that value just removes the sign bit.

Comment: I think the way it would be done is to cast the `int` to a `uint` using the `unchecked` keyword. As in `unchecked((uint)-1) = 4294967295`.

Comment: If your hashtable size is always a power of two, you don't need to use the modulus operation at all, simply use `hash & (size - 1)`.

Comment: It's bad to choose that table size(power of two). It must be prime